# Node JS, Socket.IO, Express and Http connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, socket.io

I wanted to throw an idea to you guys to see if you could provide me with an insight if something like this is possible.

Idea is that we have an RFID reader attached to a MacMini (Mini is hidden and only the RFID is visible). There is also an IPad attached and the idea is that once you tab on to the RFID reader, I want to validate the value behind the RFID card and then based on a success/error response send a notification to the IPad either to say something went wrong or to show a form which the users then has to fill out or there is some other interactions that can take place like pagination and so on. There is also a monitor attached to the MacMini and the idea here is that based on the 
interaction on the iPad, it relays this back to the MacMini (via Node web sockets as everything is browser based) and the displays the relevent information based on the interaction made.

I am not sure how to play this as my initial thinking was that the RFID reader/Mini was on port 3000 and the browser on the IPad could listen to that and when the iPad had to communicate to the MacMini that was on another port.

Am I over thinking this maybe?

Thanks

Raj

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your setup, your story is something like :

- card detected, send on mac Mini
- validation process, assume OK.
- ipad display a form to end user
- end user complete the form which is sent back to mac mini

You'll have to set up a simple "push" action from the mac mini. the answer from the ipad can even be done as simple ajax if you're more comfortable with it.

Definitely looks like something worth trying in node. As you have no browser compatibility issues, I'd have websockets (or a framework using them as http://www.socket.io ) as a top choice.

Comment: I have started some test code in node using express, socket.io and http already but as I was working on it I thought I would throw the question to SO members just to see what others thought.